# Babel 7 Unexpected token for React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I'm upgrading to Babel v7 from v6 and when I build the project I get the following error:

Syntax error: src\app\layout\components\FooterToolbar.js: Unexpected token

[image: Unexpected token <]

I'm using the following .babelrc configuration

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { "useBuiltIns": "usage", "debug": true }],
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

And finally this is my webpack config. I put the pollyfills first and then the index.js file in the entry and the babel-loader as transpiler

```
entry: ["@babel/polyfill", paths.appIndexJs],
```

```
// Process JS with Babel.
{
  test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  include: paths.appSrc,
  use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' }],
},
```

Any advice to solve this issue? Thanks a lot

EDIT: I'm using typescript in this project. This is the tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "strict": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": [
      "src"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Please edit your question so you use text of the code, not the images

Comment: Please create minimal example, I can't reproduce error with [your configuration](https://github.com/akoidan/55497745)

Comment: The only issue I see that you didn't close `<Fragment>` tag

Comment: @deathangel908 It is closed down below. Code was working before updating

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it to work by updating webpack, its plugins and adding the presets and plugins inside the webpack configuration

```
// Process JS with Babel.
{
  test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  include: paths.appSrc,
  use: [{
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: [
        ["@babel/preset-env", { modules: "commonjs" }],
        "@babel/preset-typescript",
        "@babel/preset-react"
      ],
      plugins: [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
      ]
    }
  }],
},
```

Thanks for your answers, hopefully this is useful for someone else

Comment: It would really help if you could describe steps more in detail and how the babel configs differ from '3' to '4'.

Comment: I asked a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60104995/switching-to-babel-7-causes-jest-to-show-unexpected-token